# Residue Calculus with different enclosing methods of contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Consider the following integral: $$\frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint_C f(z) dz$$ with $$f(z)= \frac{z^2+1}{z^3}$$ and $C$ is the unit circle centered at the origin.

Consider two ways to do it:

1. Enclosing the singular points inside $C$:
   This is actually its residue at $z=0$ (order = $3$). So $$\text{Res}(f(z),z=0)=\frac{1}{(3-1)!}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}(z^2+1)\bigg|_{z=0}=1$$
2. Enclosing the singular points outside $C$ (by including the point at infinity):

From the textbook I read, 1. and 2. should give the same answer. However, I have no idea how to do 2.?

Can anyone please let me know how to deal with 2.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{z^3}$ is holomorphic at $\infty$, yet still has a residue there.  There are no other singular points outsize $C$ to consider.

$$ -\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{C} f(z)\,dz=\text{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z) = -\lim_{z\to \infty} zf(z)= -1.$$

Here is a source defining the residue at infinity.

[http://www.stat.phys.titech.ac.jp/~yokoyama/note5.pdf](http://www.stat.phys.titech.ac.jp/%7Eyokoyama/note5.pdf)